# How to make sense of WCF traces

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, trace

I know how to enable WCF tracing and view them in the trace viewer tool, but I don't understand what it all means. is there documentation somewhere that explains what each of those levels means and how to make scene of all the information that is being logged.

also what is a good source to learn about a WCF request/response life cycle. all the stages that a message goes through in the WCF internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx)

In fact, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?Refinement=27&Query=service+trace+viewer+resources.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know any doc on the Service Trace Viewer - its help file and MSDN are probably the only source I would check for.

As for intro: see Juwal Lovy's excellent [WCF Essentials](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0605051) article here - quite a good intro.

Or if you can, buy the [Learning WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627) book by Michele Leroux Bustamante - one of the best around, IMO.

[image]

Marc

Comment: I hope she updates her book to include the changes/new features in the next version of WCF